# Using Brackets and MAMP to preview php file

Tags: php

I need help to preview my php file. I've been trying for days now and can't get it to work. My apache and mySQL servers are both connecting. 
I've set up my Brackets and it did open up a preview screen in Chrome but whatever i have in the file just won't show up. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me out, thanks!
Angel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here, it appears that you're probably getting a silent PHP parse error, you can check the PHP log in MAMP to confirm.

The standard PHO opening tag is

Give this a try:

```
<?php 
     echo "Hello world";
?>
```